# What will be an efficient way to Export existing old DynamoDB tables to S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-emr, amazon-kinesis

By existing tables I mean, these were created in the year 2020 each day and I want to save them to S3 and delete from DynamoDB. I came across some ways it can be achieved, I wanted to know which one would work efficiently in my case.

Note: These tables are of size around 1GB and approx 1,00,000+ items.

1. Export to S3 feature provided by DynamoDB. How to implement it from Python Script. what boto3 Api to use?
2. Will Kinesis Data Stream work? As there would be no live events occurring on the table. Can we push existing table to stream? and export it using Amazon Firehose.
3. using Amazon Elastic Map Reduce for export to S3.

Please share your take on these and do mention any other way of doing it, if there. Thanks! Appreciate for your time.

**UPDATE: I used Export to S3, but it saved the table in four different json files. Will it be easy to import it back to DynamoDB from S3 when reqiured?**

Comment: Is there a reason why you want it in S3?

Comment: Actually to keep using DynamoDB table limits, I want to delete the old tables. But before that need backup of that. So saving it to S3 bucket. Is there any other way?

Comment: Why not just use the DynamoDB backup? You can backup the table and then delete it. If you need it again you can restore from the backup.

Comment: will it not be deleted if the source table is deleted? if not then is there any limitation of how many backups can we make. Because whole point is not to extend the provisioned table limit.

Comment: It won't be deleted when you delete the table. As a matter of fact, if you delete a table in the console it asks if you want to create a backup first. I don't believe there are limits on backups, but most of the limits for DynamoDB are soft limits, so you can request an increase.

Comment: wow, Great to know, its a saviour then! Appreciate your time @JasonWadsworth . Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

The export to S3 option seems like the best choice if you really need it to be in S3. As with almost everything in AWS, if you can do it in the console you can do it via an API call. For this one, you need to use the [ExportTableToPointInTime](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_ExportTableToPointInTime.html) API, which is [export_table_to_point_in_time](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.export_table_to_point_in_time) in boto.

Comment: Thanks @Jason ! I'll update you after trying. Is there any other way to store the tables?

Comment: It worked, but the table data are split in different json files. Can we import it back to dynamodb if required?

Answer (score 0):

If you have point in time recovery enabled for your table you can use this API to export it directly: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/export-table-to-point-in-time.html

To do the export manually you'll need to use the dynamodb scan operation. You can use the boto3 paginator https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Paginator.Scan to handle the pagination.

Comment: I'll try and update you how it goes. I am concerned about the time it would take for whole process. Thanks!

Comment: You can use a segmented scan to make it go faster if you need.

Comment: I used export-table-to-point in-time. For 1.2 GB of table size it took 4 minutes. Its working great. thanks. One more query, how to import back to dynamoDB from the S3?

Comment: There is no import API to import from s3 to dynamodb. You'll have to get the objects from s3 and then use the dynamodb api to write each record in. (Use batchWriteItem).